# NSImage from Asset Catalog in Test Target

Tags: macos, nsimage, asset-catalog, xctestcase

My unit tests target needs to load an image resource for use in some of the tests, but I am having trouble loading it.

1. I have created an **asset catalog** within the test target.
2. I have added a new **image set** resource to the catalog, checked the "Mac" box in "Devices", and set its source images for both resolutions (@1x and @2x):

[image]

3. I have checked the "copy bundle resource" build phase of the test target, and it does include the asset catalog.
4. I have checked the target membership of the asset catalog and image set, and it is indeed the test target.

---

When running the tests, I am attempting to load the image using code like below:

```
guard let image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("TestSourceImage")) else {
    fatalError("Test Resource is Missing.")
}
```

...but the guard fails.

I also tried:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: MyClassTests.self)

guard let path = bundle.pathForImageResource(NSImage.Name("TestSourceImage")) else {
    fatalError("Test Resource is Missing.")
}

guard let image = NSImage(contentsOfFile: path) else {
    fatalError("Test Resource File is Corrupt.")
}
```

...but the first guard fails (can't retrieve the resource path).

I have tried both formats

```
NSImage.Name("TestSourceImage")
```

and:

```
NSImage.Name(rawValue: "TestSourceImage")
```

I have also tried `Bundle.urlForImageResource(_)`, but it fails too.

---

I have seen similar questions and answers, but they either apply to **iOS** or to resources in the **app** (main) bundle.

**What am I missing?**

---

**UPDATE:**

In the meantine, I've **worked around** the problem by adding my test image as a stand-alone image resource (*not* using asset catalogs), and  loading it with the following code:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: MyClassTests.self)
guard let url = bundle.url(forResource: "TestSourceImage", withExtension: "png") else {
    fatalError("!!!")
}
guard let image = NSImage(contentsOf: url) else {
    fatalError("!!!")
}
```

I don't need to support multiple resolutions in this case (my image is the source for an image processing algorithm; it is already assumed to be at the highest resolution necessary), and even if I did, I would just switch from **.png** to **.tiff**, I guess.

The problem seems to be that, `NSImage` does **not** have an initializer analogous to `UIImage`'s `init(named:in:compatibleWith:)`, which lets you specify the **bundle** from which to load the image (second argument).

You can instead ask a specific bundle (other than `main`) to create a resource URL and instantiate the image from that (like I did above), but this isn't compatible with asset catalogs it seems. **Further information is welcome...**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an extension on Bundle that allows to load a named image from an asset catalog:

```
extension Bundle {
    @available(OSX 10.7, *)
    open func image(forResource name: NSImage.Name) -> NSImage?
}
```

Referring to your example, you may use the following in an XCTestCase to access the image (Swift 5):

```
guard let image = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).image(forResource: "TestSourceImage") else {
    fatalError("Test Resource is Missing.")
}
```

Tested on macOS 10.14.

Comment: Thank you, it works! It's been a while and I'm not working on that project at the moment (although it's not exactly abandoned), so I had to do some searching to find it and try your solution :-)